# Trying to make a footer where social media icons are side by side of each other in the same row css

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

Its a rails app and I mostly do a lot of programming and less html/css styling.

Here is a footer that I am attempting

```
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="fbicon">
      <%= image_tag 'fb-icon-white.png'%>
    </div>
    <div class="twicon">
      <%= image_tag 'twitter-icon-white.png'%>
    </div>
    <div class="pticon">
      <%= image_tag 'pinterest-icon-white.png'%>
    </div>
  </div>
```

my thinking is that the main footer will have a large width and then the rest of the icon will take a partial width that belongs to the main one.

the app got a scss file and this is my attempt to do a three way partial css

```
.footer {
    width: 960px;
    border: 1px;

    .fbicon {
        width: 300px; 
    }

    .twicon {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .pticon {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

They are all align one stack on another. They are not on the same row which is what I am looking for. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `div` element by default has a `block` display, which has a 100% width, hence is why they stack on top of each other. You can try using `inline-block` instead:

```
.footer {
  .fbicon, .twicon, .pticon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

Or you can float them to the left:

```
.footer {
  .fbicon, .twicon, .pticon {
    float: left;
  }
}
```